# SSH with X11 forwarding to host where I don't have a home-dir

Tags: ssh, xorg, x11-forwarding, xauth

I am trying to ssh with X11 forwarding into a host where I don't have a home directory. Because of that, xauth fails and X11 doesn't seem to work. I tried to specify a home-directory in advance but I guess it doesn't export env-vars to the host.

```
zeyer@demeter:~> HOME=/tmp ssh ares -XY
Password: 
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
Last login: Mon Mar 28 11:52:57 2011 from demeter.matha.rwth-aachen.de
Have a lot of fun...
Could not chdir to home directory /home/zeyer: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/xauth:  error in locking authority file /home/zeyer/.Xauthority
zeyer@ares:/>
```

Is there any trick I can make the X11 forwarding work? I still have write access to `/tmp`. But I am not sure how to setup the xauth fake authentication data manually.

Comment: Surely you should be asking yourself (or even the system admin) why you don't have a home directory...

Comment: @Matt: I didn't needed one so far on that PC and for some reason it hasn't mounted our NFS home. But now I need to test some application on it.

Comment: Xauth-without-$HOME can be set up by writing a special `/etc/ssh/sshrc` script, but requires root privileges.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try `ssh ares -XY "HOME=/tmp bash"?`